# How can I write a recursive query on a hierarchical table such that the output is provided as nested JSON?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, postgresql-12

I have tables that are basically as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    person_id serial primary key,
    parent_person_id int REFERENCES persons (person_id),
    person_name text
);

INSERT INTO persons (person_id,parent_person_id,person_name) VALUES
    (1,NULL,'Grandpa'),
    (2,1,'Dad'),
    (3,2,'Me'),
    (4,1,'Uncle'),
    (5,4,'Cousin'),
    (6,4,'Other Cousin'),
    (7,NULL,'Bachelor Great Uncle');
    
CREATE TABLE details (
    detail_id serial primary key,
    detail text
);

INSERT INTO details (detail_id,detail) VALUES
    (1,'beard'),
    (2,'combover'),
    (3,'long-windedness'),
    (4,'pot-belly');

CREATE TABLE person_details (
    person_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES persons (person_id),
    detail_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES details (detail_id)
);

INSERT INTO person_details (person_id, detail_id) VALUES
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,2),
    (3,1),
    (3,3),
    (4,2),
    (4,4),
    (4,3),
    (5,1),
    (6,2),
    (6,4);
```

The depth of the hierarchy can be any arbitrary number (i.e., following a `parent_person_id` up the tree can take you up an unknown number of levels before you hit a person where `parent_person_id` is `NULL`). Any number of `details` (including zero) can be attached to any person. There can be many "top-level" persons (i.e., `parent_person_id` is `NULL`), with their own, associated descendant tree.

I would like to get something like the following JSON result, where each "generation" level of the JSON object has the same set of objects, and is nested within it's parent's object.

```
{
    "person ID": 1,
    "person Name": 'Grandpa',
    "details": [
        {"detail": "combover"},
        {"detail": "long-windedness"}
    ],
    "descendents": [
        {
            "person ID": 2,
            "person Name": 'Dad',
            "details": [
                {"detail":"combover"}
            ]
            "descendents": [
                {
                    "person ID": 3, 
                    "person Name": 'Me'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "person ID": 4,
            "person Name": 'Uncle'
            "descendents": [
                {
                    "person ID": 5, 
                    "person Name": "Cousin",
                    "details"[
                        "detail": "beard"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "person ID": 6, 
                    "person Name": "Other Cousin",
                    "details"[
                        "detail": "combover"
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm getting closer, albeit in sort of a clunky way. I first created a view that assembles the JSON object for each person:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW details_by_person AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE family_tree AS (
        -- top-level persons
        SELECT 
            persons.person_id,
            parent_person_id,
            1 as depth
        FROM persons
        WHERE parent_person_id IS NULL
        GROUP BY persons.person_id,persons.parent_person_id

        UNION ALL

        -- Recursive persons
        SELECT 
            t.person_id,
            t.parent_person_id,
            ft.depth + 1 AS depth
        FROM persons t
        INNER JOIN family_tree ft ON t.parent_person_id = ft.person_id
        GROUP BY t.person_id,t.parent_person_id,ft.depth
    )
    SELECT 
        persons.person_id,
        person_name AS name,
        persons.parent_person_id,
        depth,
        jsonb_build_object('details',jsonb_agg(detail)) AS details
    FROM persons
    LEFT OUTER JOIN person_details USING (person_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN details USING (detail_id)
    JOIN family_tree ft ON ft.person_id = persons.person_id
    GROUP BY persons.person_id,depth
);
```

With that done, I created a function that assembles view-creation language that gives me *almost* the desired result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_person_details_view()
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    level_depth INT;
    view_create_string TEXT;

BEGIN
    
    SELECT max(depth) FROM details_by_person INTO level_depth;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Max depth is %',level_depth;
    -- Will always need a leaf-node CTE:
    SELECT FORMAT('
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW personz AS
    WITH level_%s AS (
    SELECT 
        details_by_person.parent_person_id,
        json_build_object(
            ''id'',person_id,
            ''name'',name,
            ''details'',
            json_agg(
                details
            )
        ) AS person_json
    FROM details_by_person 
    WHERE depth = %s
    GROUP BY 
        person_id,
        parent_person_id,
        name
)',level_depth,level_depth) INTO view_create_string;
    
    level_depth = level_depth - 1; -- take us from the bottom node to the next one up
    
    WHILE level_depth > 1 LOOP --if > 2 levels max depth, construct next cte w/ next level
            
        view_create_string = view_create_string || FORMAT(',
        level_%s AS (SELECT 
            details_by_person.person_id,
            details_by_person.parent_person_id,
                json_build_object(
                    ''id'',details_by_person.person_id,
                    ''name'',details_by_person.name,
                    ''details'',json_agg(details_by_person.details),
                    ''children'',json_agg(level_%s.person_json)
                )
            AS person_json
        FROM details_by_person 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN level_%s ON level_%s.parent_person_id = details_by_person.person_id 
        WHERE depth = %s
        GROUP BY 
            details_by_person.person_id,
            details_by_person.parent_person_id,
            details_by_person.name                                                     
        )',level_depth,level_depth+1,level_depth+1,level_depth+1,level_depth);
        
        RAISE NOTICE 'Current level depth is %',level_depth;        
        level_depth = level_depth - 1;
    END LOOP;
    
    view_create_string = view_create_string || FORMAT('
        SELECT 
            details_by_person.person_id,
            details_by_person.parent_person_id,
                json_build_object(
                    ''id'',details_by_person.person_id,
                    ''name'',details_by_person.name,
                    ''details'',json_agg(details_by_person.details),
                    ''children'',json_agg(level_%s.person_json)
                )
            AS person_json
        FROM details_by_person 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN level_%s ON level_%s.parent_person_id = details_by_person.person_id 
        WHERE depth = %s
        GROUP BY 
            details_by_person.person_id,
            details_by_person.parent_person_id,
            details_by_person.name;                                                    
        ',level_depth+1,level_depth+1,level_depth+1,level_depth);
    
    --RAISE NOTICE '%',view_create_string;
    
    EXECUTE FORMAT ('%s',view_create_string);
    
    RETURN TRUE;

END;
$BODY$;
```

I'm not sure whether this approach is clever, or stupid (probably the latter), but after executing the function to create the view, I get rows with a JSON column containing the details for each top-most element, like the example here for one of the top-most elements:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Grandpa",
    "details": [
        [
            "combover",
            "long-windedness"
        ],
        [
            "combover",
            "long-windedness"
        ]
    ],
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dad",
            "details": [
                [
                    "combover"
                ]
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Me",
                    "details": [
                        [
                            "beard",
                            "long-windedness"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Uncle",
            "details": [
                [
                    "combover",
                    "pot-belly",
                    "long-windedness"
                ],
                [
                    "combover",
                    "pot-belly",
                    "long-windedness"
                ]
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Cousin",
                    "details": [
                        [
                            "beard"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Other Cousin",
                    "details": [
                        [
                            "combover",
                            "pot-belly"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is **very** close to what I want, but if you look closely, you'll see that it's duplicating the "details" object for any person with more than 1 child (e.g., 'Grandpa', 'Uncle').

Comment: If you're open to using functions, just write a recursive function, not any view at all. This is much simpler than a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Bergi The actual data I'm working with is much more complex than this example (eventually millions of rows in the table that's analogous to the "persons" table, here, and "details" actually come from 4 different tables). For performance reasons, I think I will need to create materialized views that roll up the data so it's accessible quickly in a web application.